# Select or copy the current input line in Terminal.app

Tags: macos, terminal, shell

Is there a hotkey to select all of the input text in the input line in OS X's Terminal.app?

Comment: Do you want to select with the intent to copy or with the intent to replace?

Comment: all of the above

Comment: If you want to copy and replace, I really suggest you look into `edit-and-execute-command`. It should be able to accomplish both, with a suitable minimal script as `EDITOR`.

Comment: This is going to be a bit fishy, since the command line really has no concept of selected text, nor would mouse-selected text be replaced when if you continued typing. The answer to your question is "no", but Daniel's suggestions might help you hack together a substitute. Some other things that might help: control-a and control-e can be used to jump to the beginning and end of whatever you've typed at the prompt, and you could design your own keystroke hotkeys for terminal using Automator, Services, and AppleScript GUI scripting.

Comment: @NReilingh Pinging you; as you thought about my suggestions you might be interested in what I was able to come up with.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to filter `edit-and-execute-command()` ([manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html#Miscellaneous-Commands)) through a suitable `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL`:

```
$ touch foo.sh
$ open foo.sh
```

Set `foo.sh` content to the following, and save:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# copy current command input to clipboard -- requires local session
cat $1 | pbcopy

# clear the prompt, so no command gets executed when closing this script
# comment out the following line to execute the command you entered instead
echo -n "" > $1
exit 0
```

Then make executable and set to visual:

```
$ chmod +x foo.sh
$ export VISUAL=/Users/danielbeck/foo.sh
```

On a `bash` prompt (or any `readline` powered prompt I think) you can copy the current command input by pressing `Ctrl-X Ctrl-E` to invoke `edit-and-execute-command()`.

Edit your `~/.inputrc` file to change the hotkey for that. Edit your `.bash_profile` to keep this as your `$EDITOR`/`$VISUAL` -- drawback is obvious, you'll never have a proper `$EDITOR` again, unfortunately

---

Alternatively, you could try replicating what [this user is doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994563/integrate-readlines-kill-ring-and-the-x11-clipboard), but he's using `zsh`, not `bash`.

---

<sup>The Terminal itself is unaware what part of the current line is your prompt, and what part is your input. So accessing it's lines e.g. through AppleScript wouldn't work in general.</sup>

You can, however, read the complete output of the current tab and get its last line, and, through filtering, try to remove the prompt part of it.

My prompt ends with `$`, so the following command works:

> `tell application "Terminal" tell selected tab of window 1 to do shell script "echo '" & history & "' | sed '/^$/d' | tail -n1 | cut -d$ -f2-"`

It will get the current window's current tab's `history` property, and filter it through `sed` to remove all empty lines, then get the last line using `tail`, and then remove everything up to and including the first `$` of the line (i.e. my prompt) using `cut`.

Output of this program is your current command line. Really pointless exercise:

```
~ $ osascript Library/Scripts/get_line.scpt 
 osascript Library/Scripts/get_line.scpt
```

To copy it to your clipboard at the end, change to the following:

> `tell application "Terminal" to tell selected tab of window 1 to do shell script "echo '" & history & "' | sed '/^$/d' | tail -n1 | cut -d$ -f2- | pbcopy"`

You can use *Automator* to create a *service* that receives *no input* in application *Terminal* and performs a single *Run AppleScript Script* action consisting of the above code. Save, and optionally assign a keyboard shortcut in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Services*.

Comment: Have you (or anyone else) figured out any better way to get rid of the prompt string in the last examples?

Comment: @Lri You could, in a separate `bash` process, `echo $PS1` after loading the profile files to create a good template that is them removed from output. Unfortunately, stuff like `$PWD` and `date` will break this method. Alternatively, one could backup `$PS1` into another variable temporarily, and restore it after executing the command.